# How to efficiently calculate number of times variable changes it's value in a vector in R?

Tags: r

I am processing dataset to create a single row representing a timeframe of 10 minutes data. Along with mean, min, max, etc., I am also planning to take "Number of transitions" as feature. Is there any inbuilt function to do this in R?
And if not, what would be the most efficient way to calculate this?

```
Sample Input : c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
Sample Output : 5
```

*Note : Vector I am aggregating over will be of size at most 10.*

Comment: `length(rle(x)[[1]])-1`? also, `sum(diff(x)!=0)` (though that won't work on strings).

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I was looking for. Especially using rle was brilliant idea.

Comment: @Frank checking out the source code of `rle`, it's probably much faster to use `diff` since `rle` does this internally.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Maybe... It's taking a diff of a different object (the positions of changes), though. Besides, good luck with `diff(c("A","A","B"))`. Looked for a dupe for this, but couldn't find one... I guess `sum(x[-1] != x[-length(x)])` is the fastest/best way.